# Eclipse Mercurial Plugin link is invalid?

Tags: eclipse, mercurialeclipse

I am trying to install mercurial into Eclipse Oxygen, but I get the following error.

[image]

The Mercurial plugin site states the http address as that shown below.

https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/

All other eclipse update sites seem to work fine so I don't think it is anything to do with having to configure a proxy.

Just wonder if anyone who know about plugins might be able to offer some help as I really need to get the plugin installed.

Comment: Do you have working update sites that starts with `https`? Alternatively, you can [download the whole update site as ZIP](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/get/8ef584d8b063.zip) and install it from the ZIP.

Answer (score -1):

I am the maintainer of MercurialEclipse and I can certify that the update site works fine: installing from the update site like any user would is part of the release checklist and I did just that last November with 2.4.1. After reading your question, I have also just installed the current JDK (1.8.0_161) as well as the latest Eclipse version, Oxygen.2, on a 10-year old laptop and the installation of MercurialEclipse went smoothly.

The error message means that the Java security stack on your machine cannot link the certificate presented by bitbucket.org to a known certificate authority. The certificate chain is broken somewhere: any update site hosted on bitbucket.org will fail for you.

You need to fix the JRE or JDK that you are using.

Comment: Ok.  I have JDK version 1.8.0_121 installed on the machine.  When you say fix, can you provide and other information on how I resolve the broken security chain?

Comment: Sorry, no, I can't. Like a browser, the Java machine necessarily has its own way of verifying certificates, it probably has a store of trusted CAs. Try updating to a more recent version: the JDK is at version 161.